# Installing 123-SSL from 123-reg on Apache2

Tags: ssl-certificate, apache-2.2

I've moved away from GoDaddy as I hated having to sign into their site and got a cheap ssl cert from 123-reg, however 123-reg's instructions are contradictory and their support seems to be non-existent.

My Apache2 server works fine at the moment with the cert files provided, but has almost expired. I've tried to install the 123-SSL cert from 123-Reg however the server just says 'fail' everytime I restart the server. I'm running Ubuntu v10.04.

My cert was provided by email, with all the string on one line between ----BEGIN CERTIFICATE---- [stuff here] ----END CERTIFICATE----, as was the cert I was instructed to call gs_intermediate_ca.crt.

My VHost looks like:

```
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/www.mydomain.com.crt
    #SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/gs_intermediate_ca.crt
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/gs_intermediate_ca.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/www.mydomain.com.key
```

www.mydomain.com.key is the key that I created at the same time as the CSR.

The instructions for installing are here: http://123-support.co.uk/support/answers/installing-your-ssl-apache-open-ssl-657/ however they don't really mention the 123-SSL cert, just the slightly more expensive DomainSSL, ExtendedSSL etc. Feels a bit funny asking serverfault for support on a product from a different company but I'm a bit loathed to go back to GoDaddy.

(Incidentally, the same VHost works if I replace the info with my current SSL settings for

Many thanks, Ian.

Comment: Please post the bottom of /var/log/apache2/error.log right after you try to start it up

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, the problem was I had not edited my httpd.conf to listen on port 443

```
NameVirtualHost *:443
```

and then set-up the VH on that port. I h